# Phonegap ajax post failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm using ajax in phonegap app.

It's not working at all.

Pretty simple syntax

```
$.post(
    "http://sns.hugyou.cn/index.php?m=Index&a=get_list", {
        "page": page,
        "pagesize": PAGESIZE
    },
    function(response, status) {
        alert(Home);
    },
    "json");
```

This works with any webbrowser on my phone but phonegap.

After searching the web it appears the problems is related to cross-domain ajax.

However the index.html is stored locally and there shouldn't be any problem with this.

Also I tried removing `<access origin />` line in config.xml and still no luck.

It seems to be a very common problem but I still cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Enable domain white list**
To enable that domain add this to your config:

```
<access origin="http://sns.hugyou.cn" />
```

More info can be found here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

To enable all domains you can use:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

**Enable internet**
Another thing to make sure is that you have the `INTERNET/NETWORK` permission right.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**jQuery**
Do you have it included?

**Others**
Do you get a Javascript error?